# XSLT 1.0 - help needed

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<file>
    <Header>
        <record>1</record>
        <date>20101111</date>
        <time>0200</time>
    </Header>
    <subHead>
        <record>2</record>
        <unique>123</unique>
        <time>0200</time>
    </subHead>
    <content>
        <record>4</record>
        <field1>20101111</field1>
        <field2>0200</field2>
    </content>
    <content>
        <record>4</record>
        <field1>20101111</field1>
        <field2>0200</field2>
    </content>
    <subTail>
        <record>6</record>
        <count>2</count>
        <uniquenum>123</uniquenum>
    </subTail>
    <subHead>
        <record>2</record>
        <unique>456</unique>
        <time>0300</time>
    </subHead>
    <content>
        <record>4</record>
        <field1>2010</field1>
        <field2>0300</field2>
    </content>
    <subTail>
        <record>6</record>
        <count>1</count>
        <uniquenum>456</uniquenum>
    </subTail>
    <footer>
        <record>8</record>
        <countSubhead>2</countSubhead>
    </footer>
</file>
```

the desired output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<file>
    <Header>
        <record>1</record>
        <date>20101111</date>
        <time>0200</time>
    </Header>
    <Group>
        <subHead>
            <record>2</record>
            <unique>123</unique>
            <time>0200</time>
        </subHead>
        <content>
            <record>4</record>
            <field1>20101111</field1>
            <field2>0200</field2>
        </content>
        <content>
            <record>4</record>
            <field1>20101111</field1>
            <field2>0200</field2>
        </content>
        <subTail>
            <record>6</record>
            <count>2</count>
            <uniquenum>123</uniquenum>
        </subTail>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <subHead>
            <record>2</record>
            <unique>456</unique>
            <time>0300</time>
        </subHead>
        <content>
            <record>4</record>
            <field1>2010</field1>
            <field2>0300</field2>
        </content>
        <subTail>
            <record>6</record>
            <count>1</count>
            <uniquenum>456</uniquenum>
        </subTail>
    </Group>
    <footer>
        <record>8</record>
        <countSubhead>2</countSubhead>
    </footer>
</file>
```

here my xslt transformation logic to group whenever there is a new subHead occurs then it has to be grouped as single group

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/*">

        <file>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="subHead">
                <group>

                    <xsl:copy-of select="self::subHead"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::content"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::subTail"/>
                </group>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select="footer"/>
        </file>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm hope the error is in the following-sibling code, which combines all the subsequent node into first group. could anyone help me in correct the error what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `following-sibling` statements as you suspected. Try to specify that, for each `subHead`, We only interested in the following-sibling elements having nearest preceding-sibling `subHead` equals to current `subHead` that we are processing, like so :

```
<group>
  <xsl:copy-of select="self::subHead"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::content[preceding-sibling::subHead[1] = current()]"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::subTail[preceding-sibling::subHead[1] = current()]"/>
</group>
```

Comment: @haro07 awesome, thanks for that it is working as expect, just for clarification...when u say subhead[1] then won't it check with the first subhead, I didn't quite understand that statement

Comment: @seeker no, it didn't read that way. It reads `preceding-sibling::subHead[1]`, which means the first `preceding-sibling::subHead` from current context element. You can test in any decent online xpath tester if you're not sure.about the behavior of that statement